# How to get selected fields from table using hibernate (I am not using Criteria object but CriteriaQuery object so setProjection solution won't work)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, field

I want to get selected fields from table with filters on the top of it.

For example : 
If I want to filter my results on the basis of an attribute in the table named "created_on", I would do something like http://example.com/users/?created_on = 01-12-2016

I am achieving above task by doing this :

```
public List<User> searchUser(List<SearchCriteria> params
            , int offset, int limit) {
        Session session = mysqlConnectionFactory.getSession();
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> query = builder.createQuery(User.class);
        Root r = query.from(User.class);

        Predicate predicate = builder.conjunction();
        if (params != null) {
            for (SearchCriteria param : params) {
                if (param.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(">")) {
                    predicate = builder.and(predicate,
                            builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(r.get(param.getKey()),
                                    param.getValue().toString()));
                } else if (param.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase("<")) {
                    predicate = builder.and(predicate,
                            builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(r.get(param.getKey()),
                                    param.getValue().toString()));
                } else if (param.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(":")) {
                    if (r.get(param.getKey()).getJavaType() == String.class) {
                        predicate = builder.and(predicate,
                                builder.like(r.get(param.getKey()),
                                        "%" + param.getValue() + "%"));
                    } else {
                        predicate = builder.and(predicate,
                                builder.equal(r.get(param.getKey()), param.getValue()));
                    }
                }
            }
            query.where(predicate);
        }

        List<User> Users = session.createQuery(query)
                .setFirstResult(offset).setMaxResults(limit).getResultList();

        return Users;
    }
```

Now I also wish to incorporate the functionality which will return selected fields for me, how can I do that?